# How do I handle unmatched parameters in Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I like to do something like the following:

```
.when( 
    myMock.doSomething(
        Matchers.eq( "1" )
    ) 
)
.thenReturn( "1" )
.othwerwise()
.thenThrow( new IllegalArgumentException() );
```

Of course `otherwise()` method doesn't exist but just to show you what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

(Slight disclaimer, I've never done this personally, just read about it in the javadoc)... If all of your methods on your mock interface would be ok with the same default behaviour, you could [set the default answer on your mock](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#14) in a manner like:

```
Foo myMock = Mockito.mock(Foo.class,new ThrowsExceptionClass(IllegalArgumentException.class));
Mockito.when(myMock.doSomething(Matchers.eq("1"))).thenReturn("1");
```

JavaDoc Links for: [Mockito#mock](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock%28java.lang.Class,%20org.mockito.stubbing.Answer%29) and [ThrowsExceptionClass](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/internal/stubbing/answers/ThrowsExceptionClass.html)

Alternatively, as is discussed in the [Stubbing tutorial](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2), order of the stubbing matters and last matching wins, so you might be able to also do:

```
Foo myMock = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
Mockito.when(myMock.doSomething(Matchers.any(String.class))).thenThrow(IllegalArgumentException.class);
Mockito.when(myMock.doSomething(Matchers.eq("1"))).thenReturn("1");
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Though I find it quite counter intuitive that they decided to make last the matcher win.

Comment: which is exactly why i like the custom Answer implementation approach better.  I find it much more straightforward (and more intuitive).

Comment: It's funny, I can't actually decide which is more intuitive... First Wins tends to be a pattern for searching through options (When I find it, no need to continue searching). But you could make the analogy that defining a mock like writing files to disk. If you pictured a hypothetical storage device, where every file has a 1-1 correspondence with a unique permutation of possible inputs, then whomever writes their answer to each file last should be what's read when you execute your mock (read the file).

Comment: A couple of caveats.  The first solution that you give is good, but because the default answer applies to _every_ method of the mock, you'll need to be careful if your test also calls some other method on your mock, in addition to the one that you're testing.  I'm fairly sure that the second solution that you give won't work, because the second call to `doSomething` will actually invoke the behaviour set up in the first call, so you'll get the `IllegalArgumentException` straight away.  The "last stub wins" behaviour only kicks in  when you use the "doXxx" family of stubbing methods ...

Comment: ... so in this particular case, you'd want that second call to be `doReturn("1").when(myMock).doSomething(Matchers.eq("1"));` or even just `doReturn("1").when(myMock).doSomething("1");`

Comment: That's exactly what happened. It kept on throwing exceptions so I had to revise it to something similar to Matt's answer but with respect to order of stubbing.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The second `when()` call throws the exception.

Comment: actually both of these methods ( default answer and stubbing order ) only work when you use the "doXxx" family of stubbing methods, rather than when->then

Answer (score 10):

you could create your own Answer implementation which would pay attention to the called parameters:

```
myMock.doSomething(Mockito.any(String.class)).thenAnswer( myAnswer );
```

The implementation of said answer could do something like this:

```
public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
    if ("1".equals(invocation.getArguments()[0])) {
       return "1";
    }
    else {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. I like this answer though I already have extended a Matcher to match one of the parameters which is a map. Is there a way to use my existing Matchers against invocation.getArguments()?

Comment: If understand your question correctly, I would say pass it (or them) as a constructor argument to your Answer implementation, and simply call matcher.matches() against the appropriate argument (s).

Answer (score 5):

Just use opposite condition i.e. consider your example itself. You may want to use `not(eq())` when you need `otherwise` :

```
 .when( myMock.doSomething(Matchers.eq( "1" )))
     .thenReturn( "1" )
 .when( myMock.doSomething(not(Matchers.eq( "1" ))))
     .thenThrow( new IllegalArgumentException() );
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is that every time I need to add new matcher, I would have to add the opposite of that matcher. Say I might have 20 matchers and that will require me to add 20 opposite conditions of those. Is there really no better way of doing that?

Comment: @supertonsky Think of simple Java. In plain Java, `while` doesn't have any `otherwise`. The syntax of while is : do something when condition is satisfied. Same here. We arrange our Java code to deal with our needs. We need to apply similar concept here.

Comment: I beg to disagree. "while" is an iteration construct not a conditional construct. "when" is more of a conditional construct like "if". I'm looking for a solution that works like an "else" and not something like another "if" that simply reverses the condition of the previous "if"s just to be caught.

Comment: @supertonsky: I didn't mean to say, `when` is exactly same a `while` in Java.  All i said that, `when`'s body is executed when the condition is satisfied same as `while`'s body based on the condition. I tried to explain the similarity only to explain there is no else here.  `while` was used just for the example. I am not sure where is the disagreement. There are other constructs which can be use the achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: You could actually make a "while" to work like an "if" and vice versa. I just don't prefer working my way through code hacks if more elegant solution exists or proper constructs are provided. In the end it's about using the right tool for the right job.

Comment: It's not clear where the `not` comes from here - it's from the `org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers`.

Answer (score 3):

The way described by the accepted answer by @Charlie doesn't work (anymore).
When you try to override the general throw exception behaviour for some argument the first rule is triggered and you have an exception (just as you asked).

```
Mockito.when(myMock.doSomething(any()))
    .thenThrow(IllegalArgumentException.class);
Mockito.when(myMock.doSomething(eq("1"))).thenReturn("1"); //An exception is thrown here
// because of the call to .doSomething() on the mock object
```

To avoid that call one can use `Mockito.doReturn()` method:

```
Mockito.when(myMock.doSomething(any()))
    .thenThrow(IllegalArgumentException.class);
Mockito.doReturn("1").when(myMock).doSomething(eq("1"));
```

The initial issue is one of reasons why `doReturn()` exists according to it's javadoc:

```
Here are those rare occasions when doReturn() comes handy:
<...some lines are skipped...>
Overriding a previous exception-stubbing:

hen(mock.foo()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
//Impossible: the exception-stubbed foo() method is called so RuntimeException is thrown.
when(mock.foo()).thenReturn("bar");

//You have to use doReturn() for stubbing:
doReturn("bar").when(mock).foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

With java 8 lambda you can do:

```
myMock.doSomething(Mockito.any(String.class)).thenAnswer(invocation -> {    
    Object arg = invocation.getArguments()[0];
    if ("1".equals(arg)) {
        return "1";
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected 1 but got " + arg);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can use verify, as follows:

```
when(myMock.doSomething("1")).thenReturn( "1" );
assertEquals(myMock.doSomething("1"),"1");
verify(myMock).doSomething("1")
```